# Quantum of Energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, photons

We know that energy of a photon is $E=hf$. So, a photon of frequency $1$ will have energy equal to the Planck constant. Is this the minimum possible energy exchange possible or a photon of frequency less than $1$ is possible?

Comment: There is no lower bound to the energy a photon can have. But the energy of a photon *does* come in discrete packets, as it is quantised. (Energy can only be the integral multiples of $h\nu$)

Comment: *"will have energy equal to the Planck constant"* - $h$ has units of action (or angular momentum), not energy.  When you write *"a photon of frequency 1"*, it should be *"a photon of frequency $1 \mathrm{Hz}$"* to help keep this straight.

Answer (score 0):

Frequency can assume value less than 1 for example 1*10^(-10) , but quantum packets of energy are collections of such photons so they by themselves are not bounded by whole number but their collective sum is (they wait until they assume required value like a queue to a bus), to be considered a definite
quanta of energy.
But I understand what you are trying to ask what is the minimum value for a discrete quanta , for that matter , normal matter has some minimum amount of mass thus has energy but a photon having zero rest mass relies on its vibrations but is said to have mass of m < 3×10^(−27)* eV/c^2 thus has minimum energy related to this mass given by energy mass equivalence.